# Getting a copy of Tomcat 8 examples running in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, security, ubuntu, tomcat

I want to play with the Tomcat examples from the Ubuntu repository, that came in the package `tomcat8-examples`. They are installed in `/usr/share/tomcat8-examples`. And they have their policy entry `/etc/tomcat8/policy.d/10examples.policy`. Here's the text:

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" {
       permission java.io.FilePermission "/usr/share/tomcat8-examples/examples/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties", "read";
};
```

Now I copied the contents of the examples to my own folder in `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps`. But Tomcat won't deploy it, not even the main index.html.

I gather I need to set up a policy for it, one like the original examples have. Thus, something along these lines:

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" {
       permission java.io.FilePermission "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/start/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties", "read";
};
```

`/var/lib/tomcat8/` is the value of `$CATALINA_BASE`, btw.

Now I'm not sure where to place this policy. I tried to append it to `/var/cache/tomcat8/catalina.policy`, but it didn't work. My next thought is `/etc/tomcat8/policy.d`. But... A tip would be nice. Also if you know some ***easy*** overview of the security matters for servlets & co, that would be nice too. (I know Tomcat covers this in their documentation, and I mean something still ***easier***.) Thanks.

EDIT

If someone could explain what and why is this (and not or also something else):
`permission java.io.FilePermission "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/start/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties", "read";`
that would be great.

EDIT

localhost_access_log.2016-07-15.txt:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2016:20:38:53 +0200] "GET /start HTTP/1.1" 404 1022
```

Tomcat Web Application Manger, after I start the service from there:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /start could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/start]]
```

localhost_access_log.2016-07-15.txt, after starting as above:

```
15-Jul-2016 20:46:11.381 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: init: Associated with Deployer 'Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost'
15-Jul-2016 20:46:11.382 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: init: Global resources are available
15-Jul-2016 20:46:11.404 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
15-Jul-2016 20:46:20.358 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/start'
15-Jul-2016 20:46:20.431 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log FAIL - Application at context path /start could not be started
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/start]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1293)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:666)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:304)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1890)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:780)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Why are you messing-around with the policy file *at all*? Are you even running Tomcat under a SecurityManager? What do the logs say?

Comment: Thanks. I added the logs to my question. I don't know why I thought about policies. It was intuitive. I don't know if Tomcat's under SecurityManager, nor what that means, nor where to check that. But I had to introduce users and roles after install, so that the http manager would work, if that's of import here.

Comment: And as stated in my question, the original examples have a policy, so I thought I need one too for my copy.